# Can I reverse the orientation of a datagridview cleanly?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

In a WinForms C# application is it possible to cleanly (without making a custom control) bind a list to a DataGridView and then reverse the orientation to vertical? The top portion of this image is what I have now, the bottom is how I want it to look:

[image]

Or do I need to simply give up on the binding and populate it manually or back down and use a listview?

Some of the code (on Parse Message button):

```
dgvSend.DataSource = null;
List<mbusRTUSend> messages = new List<mbusRTUSend>();
messages.Add(new mbusRTUSend(tbSMsg.Text));
dgvSend.DataSource = messages;
```

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19313/Displaying-Vertical-Rows-in-DataGrid-View

Comment: How is this going to work out once you add *more* than one row to the grid?  If you only ever consider adding one row then a grid isn't the right control.  If you want to display just one row, like the selected one, then that's easily done with a UserControl or Form and binding its controls isn't a problem.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not sure what the problem with multiple rows would be; they would extend to the right instead of down